# Convert relative/viewport size to fixed size on page load using JavaScript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, viewport-units

hope you are having a nice day. I am currently developing a website, in which pretty much all of my measurements (font size, padding, margin, width, height, etc) are made with the viewport units vw and vh.

I use these units because they are the best to make the page look like what I want on different screen resolutions, unlike pixel sizes.

What I was wondering if it's possible, is to after the page loads, get the non-relative value of all those measurements (for example, if I say 1vw, and my screen is 1000px, the non-relative value should be 10px) and replace the relative values on my css3 sheet with those. This may sound ridiculous, but my point with this is to allow the user to zoom in and out of the page, and have things actually zoom in or out. currently, no matter what kind of zooming the user does, the page stays the same except for a repeating image I have.

I would like to do this in javascript, since its the language I know the most for client-side scripts in html, due to my java origins.

Alternatively, maybe there is a feature I dont know that simply ignores the relative values when zooming in? if so, please let me know.

Comment: hot damn, this must be a really difficult question, not even a guess yet :| I will keep waiting

Comment: Why? You "*I use these units because they are the best to make the page look like what I want on different screen resolutions, unlike pixel sizes.*" So, why are you changing to pixel-sizing on page-load? What's the benefit? Or the problem that you're trying to solve? Because this doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @DavidThomas The page looks fine, and adapts to different resolution sizes (like I wanted) but it doesnt allow the user to zoom in/out. If the user finds the fonts to be too big/small, (s)he cant change the size of anything, because it resizes based on viewport, so the size is scaled and everything looks the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be something like this (tested in Chrome and IE); it adapts to the viewport on page load and reload, but doesn't adapt to subsequent viewport resizes and zooms.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="content-type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<META NAME="viewport" CONTENT="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<STYLE TYPE="text/css">
BODY {font-size: 2vw;}
DIV {width: 50vw; height: 66vh; background-color: pink; overflow: hidden;}
H1 {font-size: 200%; font-weight: bold; margin-bottom: -.5vw}
@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {H1 {color: blue;}}
H2 {font-size: 4vmin; font-style: italic;}
P {font-size: 100%; line-height: 1.5em;}
</STYLE>
<SCRIPT>
function fixedSizes()
{
    var w = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
    var h = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientheight;
    var units = {vw: w / 100, vh: h / 100, vmin: (w > h ? h : w) / 100, vmax: (w > h ? w : h) / 100};
    var sheet = addSheet();

    for (var s = 0; s < document.styleSheets.length - 1; s++)
    {
        var rules = document.styleSheets[s].cssRules || document.styleSheets[s].rules;

        for (var r = 0; r < rules.length; r++)
        {
            var rule = rules[r];

            if (rule.type == CSSRule.STYLE_RULE)
            {
                var selector = rule.selectorText;
                var styles = rule.style.cssText.match(/[\w-]+\s?:\s?-?[\d\.]+(vw|vh|vmin|vmax)/g);

                for (var t = 0; styles && t < styles.length; t++)
                {
                    var style = styles[t];
                    var prop = style.match(/^[\w-]*/)[0];
                    var unit = style.match(/(vw|vh|vmin|vmax)$/)[0];
                    var val = parseFloat(style.match(/-?[\d\.]+(vw|vh|vmin|vmax)/)[0]) * units[unit];
                    addStyle(sheet, selector, prop + ": " + val + "px");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function addSheet()
    {
        var s = document.createElement("style");
        s.type = "text/css";
        s.rel = "stylesheet";
        s.media = "screen";
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);
        return(document.styleSheets[document.styleSheets.length - 1]);
    }

    function addStyle(sheet, selector, style)
    {
        if (sheet.addRule)
        {
            sheet.addRule(selector, style);
        }
        else if (sheet.insertRule)
        {
            sheet.insertRule(selector + " { " + style + " }");
        }
    }       
}

if (CSSRule)
{
    if (document.addEventListener)
    {
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", fixedSizes, false);
    }
    else if (window.attachEvent)
    {
        window.attachEvent("onload", fixedSizes);
    }
}
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<DIV>
<H1>Viewport Units</H1>
<H2>Converted to Pixel Values</H2>
<P>Probably the best way to do this for fonts,<BR>is to set the font sizes as percentages,<BR>
   and then have javascript change the BODY font size.</P>
</DIV>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Just to explain what's happening: this checks the current viewport size, then runs through all the stylesheets, looking for properties that have a value set in viewport units, converts the value to pixels, and adds the converted css rules to a new stylesheets that is appended after the other stylesheets.

Of course, if only a few styles need updating, you could put them together in a seperate stylesheet, and have the script only look at those. Or you could even just add the styles verbatim, like:

```
addStyle(document.styleSheets[0], "H1", "font-size: " + w * 0.04 + "px");
addStyle(document.styleSheets[0], "P", "font-size: " + w * 0.02 + "px");
```

Also, don't set any sizes inside media queries; that would change the lay-out while resizing and zooming.

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer, on my way to test it now. just an FYI though: when using the script tag on html5 you no longer need to declare what kind of script it is, you can just do <script></script>.

Comment: So, I tested your code (btw you are missing a ";" in your last script line) and it doesnt seem to be working for me. I placed an alert at the end of your code but it doesnt seem to fire, so I guess it doesnt get to the end of your function. There are no errors though, so possibily its a logic error that I'm not getting yet. can you upload a demo please?

Comment: Oops, I forgot to test whether "styles" existed before using "styles.length"; I probably changed the css afterwards, that's why the bug didn't show up at first.

Comment: I tweaked the script a bit more for browser compatibility. However, I found that e.g. IE8 discards css rules it doesn't understand (like those with viewport units) completely, so they're missing from the document.styleSheets interface. So there isn't much point in trying to get this script to work with browsers of IE8 vintage; I don't know whether that is important to you.
You can provide a fallback for older browsers by setting a sensible pixel value first, like "P {font-size: 16px; font-size: 2vh}".

Comment: well this didnt really work for me, but it seems like its a good script for anyone trying to do this in the future, so I'm marking this as the correct answer, and going to find some work around. (I will probably change a lot how my website works, since its kind of confusing right now).

Comment: Thanks. Just to clarify to future readers:  
- As it is, the script only works for modern browsers that understand viewport units. Workaround idea: assume e.g. a viewport width of 1024px as a fallback for older browsers, use double styles like {width: 512px; width: 50vw}, then if the script finds the pixel value, multiply it by (w / 1024).  
- Styles inside media queries are ignored, because they wouldn't make sense in this particular case. You'll have to split the media rule into seperate style rules first.  
- "!important" is ignored. Check out CSSStyleDeclaration.getPropertyPriority().

Comment: one more thing @m69, if you think this question was useful, upvote it (if you dont mind). once I get 15 rep I'll vote your answer up :)