# viewport unit to pixels when dealing with images

Tags: css, pixel, image-scaling, viewport-units

Ive been using the viewport unit to set the width and height on my images for my website. I was wondering if there was a way to convert vh/vw to pixels, so I could resize my images to those specific pixels. The following is my code/measurements.

```
#left > img:nth-of-type(1) {
  height: 65vh;
  width: 78vw;
}
#left > img:nth-of-type(2) {
  height: 90vh;
  width: 78vw;
}
#left, #right {
  display: inline-block;
}
#top-right, #bottom-right {
  display: block;
}
#top-right > img:nth-of-type(1) {
  width: 75vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
#top-right > img:nth-of-type(2) {
  width: 45vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
#bottom-right > img:nth-of-type(1) {
  width: 70vw;
  height: 55vh;
}
#bottom-right > img:nth-of-type(2) {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 55vh;
}
```

Comment: Fwiw, you can determine the current pixel size of any element, using e.g. `offsetWidth` and `offsetHeight` properties in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

> I was wondering if there was a way to convert vh/vw to pixels

No, because `vw` or `vh` is a **relative** value (relative to the current device screen size), whereas pixel dimensions are an **absolute** value. You can only get the pixel value on a *Per-instance* basis, rather than on a *fits-every-screen-size* basis.

See also [this post as a potential answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30503301/convert-relative-viewport-size-to-fixed-size-on-page-load-using-javascript-jquer). This Javascript can then load the page on the client device and then feedback translations of what the `vw` / `vh` / *etc.* values are in absolute pixels, but these pixel values will change on every different screen size/densty that the page is viewed on.

instead you can try using `min-width` / `max-width` / *etc.* values and setting them to the desired pixel size. This will set a ***minimum*** and ***maximum*** size that the **viewport-relative** size can then scale between.

```
#left > img:nth-of-type(2) {
   height: 90vh;
   width: 78vw;
   min-width: 120px; /* Set these as you require */
   max-width: 640px;
   min-height: 140px;
   max-height: 700px;
}
```